# Search an hash in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an object like this in ES :

```
{
  _index: products_development_20141007185853021
  _type: product
  _id: 5039
  _version: 1
  _score: 1
  _source: {
    name: Le Moelleux - Gâ teau tout Chocolat
    quantity: 500
    quantity_unit: gram
    store_ids: [
      503
      504
      505
    ]
    name_suggest: Le Moelleux - Gâ teau tout Chocolat
    store_prices: [{
      id: 503
      price: 2.65
    } {
      id: 504
      price: 2.65
    } {
      id: 505
      price: 2.65
    } ]
    product_categories: [{
      id: 109
      name: Viennoiserie
      parent: {
        id: 105
        name: Pain,
        viennoiserie,
        biscotte
        parent_id: 92
        tags: [
          pains et viennoiseries
          biscotte
          tartine
          biscottes tartines
          boulangerie
          pâ tisseries moelleuses
        ]
      }
    }]
    product_brand: {
      id: 1134
      name: KER CADELAC
      type: null
    }
    store_company: {
      id: 4
      name: Chronodrive
    }
    categories_and_ancestors: [{
      id: 109
    } {
      id: 105
    } {
      id: 92
    }]
  }
}
```

With this mapping:

```
mappings: {
  product: {
    properties: {
      item_count: {
        type: integer
      }
      name_suggest: {
        search_analyzer: whitespace_analyzer
        index_analyzer: nGram_analyzer
        type: string
      }
      store_company: {
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: string
          }
          id: {
            type: long
          }
        }
      }
      quantity_unit: {
        index: not_analyzed
        type: string
      }
      quantity: {
        type: double
      }
      store_ids: {
        type: string
      }
      store_prices: {
        properties: {
          price: {
            type: double
          }
          id: {
            type: integer
          }
        }
      }
      categories_and_ancestors: {
        properties: {
          id: {
            type: integer
          }
        }
      }
      product_categories: {
        properties: {
          parent: {
            properties: {
              parent_id: {
                type: long
              }
              name: {
                type: string
              }
              id: {
                type: long
              }
              tags: {
                type: string
              }
            }
          }
          name: {
            type: string
          }
          id: {
            type: integer
          }
        }
      }
      name: {
        analyzer: product_analyzer
        type: string
      }
      product_brand: {
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: string
            fields: {
              raw: {
                index: not_analyzed
                type: string
              }
            }
          }
          id: {
            type: integer
          }
          type: {
            type: string
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How Can i make a request or filter to get all documents where store_prices has not:

```
{
  id: 503
  price: 0
}
```

I mean the full object. I want to translate this query in ES :

```
select from products where store_prices does not include { id: 503, price: 0 }
```

thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing store_prices in your mapping.

Comment: Oups, I did not pasted the good mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the tuple {id: 503, price: 0} not to be contained in that array of tuples (and matching entire tuples, not "id" from one tuple and "price" from another), then you can't. You need nested objects. The best explanation for this is [here, in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays).

For that to work you need this mapping for store prices:

```
"store_prices": {
  "type": "nested", 
  "properties": {
    "price": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

And to query (filter) for the mapping above, you'd use this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "store_prices",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      { "match": {"store_prices.id": "503"}},
                      { "match": {"store_prices.price": "2.65"}}
                    ]
                  }}}}
          ]}}}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am waiting maybe some others answer and then accept yours.